# Chrome fails to load once installed on latest Kali

Tags: google-chrome, kali-linux

I installed Google Chrome on the latest Kali (running in Virtualbox on Windows 10)

```
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:        2022.1
Codename:       kali-rolling
```

using instructions given on this website: https://www.tecmint.com/install-google-chrome-on-kali-linux/

To install I ran:

```
sudo apt update
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Everything went smoothly. However when I run it with:

```
google-chrome --no-sandbox
```

I get the following error:
[image]

Error in text format:

```
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[43839:43839:0305/011538.609893:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(188)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
```

I've googled around but can't seem to find a solution.
Any ideas?

Comment: What Graphics controller have you chosen in Virtualbox for this VM, how much VRAM and is 3D acceleration enabled?

Comment: @Robert - Graphics Controller is VMSVGA, Base Memory is 4096MB, Video Memory is 128MB and 3D Acceleration is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

From all my research on this error, this problem is seen quite a lot when it comes to VM's in general, from testing I can say I haven't seen this problem pop up near as much on proper OS' (i.e Kali bootable USB|Kali Bare Metal) compared to a Virtual OS!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1126524)